# Multicast packages are not passing through the router when using WiFi

Tags: router, publish-subscribe, multicast, data-distribution-service, opendds

I have a pretty simple setup, two computers connected to each other through an ASUS RT-AC87U router and what I am trying to do is to send some packages from one to the other (running a publisher-subscriber application) using RTPS and Multicast.

Things work fine when they are connected over Ethernet (or the client:WiFi, server:Ethernet).
I am using wireshark in both computers to sniff the outgoing and ingoing packages.

Do you have any ideas on what can the problem be?
I have already experimented with the related configuration that I could think of in the router settings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/issues/1609 for a similar issue and things to look at